# How to replace using a regexp from the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, terminal

I want to replace in `index.html` using one of the default debian linux tool the following:

```
="([A-z]+).html"
```

with

```
="javadoc/$1.html"
```

`index.html` file contains the following:

```
<frame src="overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame" title="All Packages">
<frame src="allclasses-frame.html" name="packageFrame" title="All classes and interfaces (except non-static nested types)">
</frameset>
<frame src="overview-summary.html" name="classFrame" title="Package, class and interface descriptions" scrolling="yes">
Link to <a href="overview-summary.html">Non-frame version</a>.</p>
```

I have started using `sed` but I have expression error:

```
sed -E 's,="([^"]+)\.html",="javadoc\/\1.html",' public/javadoc/index.html
```

Comment: `"I want to replace"` (what?) `"in index.html ..."` and `sed -E "s/=\"([A-z-]+)\"/\1something\2/"` has only 1-capture but uses `\1...\2` (e.g. 2) backreferences??

Comment: Try `sed -E 's,="([^"]+)\.html",javadoc/\1.html,' public/javadoc/index.html`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, you should have posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed "s/\([^\"]*\.html\)/javadoc\/\1/g" public/javadoc/index.html
```

explanation

```
s/                # substitute
\(                # start arg1
[^\"]*\.html      # all char before .html without "
\)                # end of arg1
/javadoc\/\1      # replace with javadoc/arg1
/g                # global on whole line
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it yours perfectlly correct

```
sed -E 's,="([^"]+)\.html",="javadoc/\1.html",' public/javadoc/index.html
```